Container to Container communication in Docker Node for Browser based calls
I am creating a docker compose based local project. It has following properties


It has a frontend created out of nginx web server exposed at port 80, mapped to host port 8080.
It has backend created out of .NET exposed at port 3000, mapped to host port 8081.

These two are on same network ie TodoApi.
If I do ping backend from terminal of frontend, all packets are received ie backend is accessible from frontend with in docker network.
But If I try to make a call from frontend index.html to backend using http://backend/get it fails with host not resolvable which is understandable as backend is only resolvable via Docker DNS.
My understanding it to make frontend talk to backend, when we making browser based calls is via http://hostip:8081 is the only way.
Is this understanding correct? otherwise please enlighten.
Here is link to the mentioned project for referene TodoListApp.

Your frontend application is running in the end user's browser, even if its code is served from a container.  The browser isn't in a container and can't see the Docker-network hostnames.
